# Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error on Centos

Tags: linux, centos

I'm trying to install yq on CentOS 9 on hetzner.

```
 wget https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/download/v4.27.5/yq_linux_arm64 && chmod +x yq_linux_arm64 && ./yq_linux_arm64
```

The error is:

```
bash: ./yq_linux_arm64: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Arch info:

```
[root@centos-2gb-nbg1-1 ~]# uname -a
Linux centos-2gb-nbg1-1 5.14.0-148.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 19 13:03:55 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You downloaded a binary compiled for an ARM CPU and are trying to execute it on a X86 CPU.

The correct binary should be `yq_linux_amd64`